# Calculate number in polynomial sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I would like to calculate a number in a sequence directly without calculating the whole sequence.

The sequence goes like this

$$1000-100(0.5^0) = 900$$
$$900-100(0.5^1)=850$$
$$850-100(0.5^2)=825$$
$$825-100(0.5^3)=812.5$$

If I have my starting value of $1000$, how can I calculate  $x-100(0.5^n)$  without calculating every number in the sequence to get $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any value of $n\in\mathbb N$, the value you're looking for can be found by \begin{align*}
1000-100(0.5)^0-100(0.5)^1-\cdots -100(0.5)^n&=1000-100(1+0.5+0.5^2+\cdots +0.5^n)
\end{align*}
Note that the sum in the parentheses is the sum of a geometric progression. Using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, \begin{align*}
1000-100(1+0.5+0.5^2+\cdots +0.5^n)&= 1000-100\left(\frac{1-0.5^{n+1}}{1-0.5}\right)\\
&= 1000-100\left(\frac{1-0.5^{n+1}}{0.5}\right)\\
&= 1000-200(1-0.5^{n+1})
\end{align*}

Comment: As you may be able to tell, I am not very advanced in math.  I called it a "polynomial sequence".  That isn't the correct term is it?  It is actually a geometric progression, right?  Maybe that is why I couldn't find what I needed by searching for help on polynomials.